# can't center the image using background-position

Tags: html, css

I'm very new in all in this area, so sorry if it looks like clumsy code.

I'm trying to do something that apparently looks easy.
I have an image that it also link to other url and I can't put in the center of the page.
if I'm using the background-position=center without the link it working fine (with some modification) , and when I'm adding the link it showing at the top of the page.
what I'm doing wrong?

at head and style i have this lines:

> `#main`
>                   {
>                           background-image:url('google.png');
>                           background-repeat:no-repeat;
>                           background-position:center;
>                           display: block;
>                           margin: 0 auto;
>                           text-indent: -9999px;
>                           width: 137px;
>                           height: 137px;
>                   }

and in the body I have this line:

> `<body>`
>              `<a href="http://www.google.com" id="main">google</a>`
>   `</body>`

Thanks,
Reuven

Comment: This sort of thing? http://jsfiddle.net/T868X/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make link `display: inline-block` and put inside div with style `text-align: center`;
[Example](http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/nzBvt)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to place your image-link to the center of the page, try changing your css margin part to:

```
margin: 50% auto;
```

Is this what you meant?

Positioning a background image in an anchor is relative just to the anchor, not the whole page. This is probably why it works for you without the link. If you don't want the text 'google' to appear, you can simply remove it.

Have a look at the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/638Y4/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I changed the margin to 50% and it worked like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome. However, it is not really center of the page, image's top border is placed at the middle of the page. So, more precise solution would be: margin: calc(50% -  half_Image_height) auto.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding a `div` to `anchor` and set `text-align:center;`

like

`<div style="text-align:center;"><a href="http://www.google.com" id="main">google</a></div>`